# Is there a way to check for integers when there are commas in the value?

Tags: php, integer

Typical values that are stored in my DB table as follows:

```
 $value1 = "123,232,453";
 $value2 = "123,232,453.45";
```

Commas and decimals. I have to detect if there has been any error in data entry after the data has been uploaded. The uploading process is a blackbox to me and it's likely that there is a number_format going on there.

I tried

```
  ctype_digit($value1)
```

to check but the commas are not being of any help.

Is there a way to check for integers when there are commas in the value?

Comment: Just remove the commas and check?

Comment: `if(ctype_digit(str_replace(",","",$value)))`

Comment: you should be storing actual numbers in your db, especially if you need to be treating those values as numbers. numbers-as-strings just forces you to do repeated string->number conversions and performance will be painful. save the human-readable formatting when it's time to do OUTPUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply strip out the commas by treating the input as a string:

```
$value1 = str_replace(',', '', $value1);
```

Then you can check for integers using a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^-?\d+$/', $value1)) {
    ...
}
```

Or, if decimals are allowed, you can use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

```
if (is_numeric($value1)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `is_numeric` is not valid for integers

Comment: I know the OP mentioned integers in the question  but one of the sample inputs is `123,232,453.45` which isn't an integer but still considered to be valid input by the OP.

Comment: You could put the `,` in a character class with `\d` then you don't need to strip.

Comment: @chris85 True. That would complicate the regex since we would then need to make sure that input such as `",,,"` is considered invalid. Maybe the resulting regex would be `/^-?\d+[0-9,]*$/`.

Comment: Oh yea, didn't think about an only comma input.

Answer (score 0):

To check for commas:

```
if(strpos($value, ",")){
     // there is a comma
}else{
     // there is no comma
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a more functional style and avoiding regex one could do it this way:

```
$values[] = "123,232,453";
$values[] = "123,232,453.45";
$values[] = "123,232,453.45b";

$result = array_map(
    function ($val) {
        return array_reduce(
            explode(",", $val),
            function ($carry, $item) {
                return $carry && filter_var($item, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) !== false;
            }, true
        );
    }, $values
);

var_dump($result);
```

This will output the following on cli. The last element will be false as the last test case contains non valid numbers.

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  bool(true)
  [1] =>
  bool(true)
  [2] =>
  bool(false)
}
```

For all items in `values` it explodes the item at `,` and then use a filter to check if each result is a valid float/number.